# How to ignore Property on JSON deserialization?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

My Dto has `Id` property:

```
  public class ADto
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Text { get; set; }
  }
```

The `Id` is set by EF Core not by Frontend request, so I want to ignore it on deserialization ( but do not ignore on serialization, so already set Id by EF Core will be returned to Frontend), how to achieve that with attributes? I am using `using System.Text.Json.Serialization;`.

Deserialization is done by ASP. NET Core, I need to implement it as an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve exactly what you want with the [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonattribute) built in to System.Text.Json as of .NET 8 or earlier.

As a workaround, in .NET 7 and later you could create a [custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/creating-custom-attributes), then check for it in a custom [typeInfo modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers) when generating [contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts) for your types.

First define the following attribute:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class JsonIgnoreOnDeserializationAttribute : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonAttribute
{
    public static void Apply(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo)
    {
        if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
            return;
        foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
        {
            if (property.AttributeProvider?.IsDefined(typeof(JsonIgnoreOnDeserializationAttribute), true) == true)
                property.Set = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And modify your type as follows:

```
public class ADto
{
    [JsonIgnoreOnDeserialization]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when setting up your serialization options, apply the modifier in .NET 8 by calling [`WithAddedModifier()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsontypeinforesolver.withaddedmodifier) like so:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    // If you are using source generation, use SourceGenerationContext.Default here instead.
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver() 
        .WithAddedModifier(JsonIgnoreOnDeserializationAttribute.Apply),
    // Add other options as required, e.g.:
    WriteIndented = true,
};
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hp5rki).

Notes:

- The extension method [`WithAddedModifier()`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-8/#ijsontypeinforesolver-withaddedmodifier) is new in .NET 8 and allows for modification of contracts of arbitrary `IJsonTypeInfoResolver` instances, including  both both [`DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver) and [`JsonSerializerContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonserializercontext).

  In .NET 7, use `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` and set the modifier explicitly:

  ```
  var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
  {
      TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver() 
      {
          Modifiers = { JsonIgnoreOnDeserializationAttribute.Apply },
      },
      // Add other options as required, e.g.:
      WriteIndented = true,
  };
  ```

  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4fH0ni).
- .NET 8 also has the ability to serialize properties that are entirely nonpublic, so you could consider modifying `ADto` by marking `Id` with `[JsonIgnore]` and adding a private get-only surrogate property like so:

  ```
  public class ADto
  {
      public ADto() { }

      [JsonInclude, JsonPropertyName("Id")]
      private int DeserializedId => Id;

      [JsonIgnore]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Text { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  In .NET 7 and earlier the surrogate property would need to be public, which you probably would not want.

  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3erkSo).

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach, without attributes, simple and clear:

```
var id = myDto.Id;  // Save the Id
myDto = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<aDto>(json);
myDto.Id = id;      // Restore the Id
```

Comment: Deserialization is done by ASP. NET Core, I need to implement it as an attribute.
 I don't know what code above actually solves, it doesn't cause ignoring Id on deserialization.

Comment: You did not originally mention that ASP .Net Core does the deserializing. Also, even in that case this approach could still be usable. The `Id` comes from EF Core you say, well put it over the Id that is deserialized - or if your scenario makes that impossible then I invite you to show in the question why that would be impossible.